# How to modify a template of a reusable app in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

For example, let's say I want to modify the `breadcrumbs` block of the `admin/change_list.html` template in the Django admin. If I try to override this template like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block breadcrumbs %} ... my changes ... {% endblock %}
```

then Django goes into an infinite recursion when trying to load my override, because the "extends" tag tries to load the override rather than the original template.

An obvious way would be to copy & paste the entire source template, but this is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. So how can I modify a template without copying and pasting all of it into my project?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967801/django-overriding-and-extending-an-app-template

Comment: @gotgenes I have no objections to them being merged, although strictly speaking _that_ is a duplicate of _this_ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete details on overriding the admin templates are here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates.

If you're only trying to change the template for a single app, you can simply save it as `app_label/change_list.html`. If you're trying to change it for a single model, you can save it as `app_label/model_as_underscores/change_list.html`.

If you're trying to change it for all your stuff, you can create a new template with a different name, and set its name as the `change_list_template` attribute on all your `ModelAdmin` subclasses. (On `ModelAdmin`, you can do the same thing with `change_form_template`, `delete_confirmation_template`, and `object_history_template`. On an `AdminSite`, you can override the `index_template` and `login_template` attributes in the same way.)

Both of these methods will allow you to extend from the original admin templates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I wanted to override the block for all apps. Added `admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template = "admin/myproject_change_list.html"` at the end of my `admin.py` and that did it. Not completely "clean" but certainly good enough.